# Installing EWZRecaptchaBundle in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, bundle, recaptcha

I'm using symfony 2.4.0, and I want to install the EWZRecaptchaBundle to add a captcha to my forms, so I added this line to composer.json

```
"require": {
         //...
        "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "2.0.*"
        //...
    }
```

And I run this command

```
composer update
```

But it doesn't install the bundle successfully, and this is the error message I get, in the command

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle could not be found in
any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
imum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common
 problems.
```

For the record, this is the Github link to the bundle I want to install :

https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle

Any idea??

**Notes:**

- I use the command line as an Administrator.
- I tested also with this line : ""excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "dev-master"
- The same result when I set minimum stability setting to : "dev" or "stable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this require:

```
"excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "dev-master"
```

Because `2.0.x-dev` are in development now. or use old stable version:

```
"excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "v1.0.0"
```

Comment: I already tried with dev-master, and in vain... I'll give a try to "v1.0.0"

Comment: What about `"excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "*"` ?

Comment: I'm waiting for the "v1.0.0" ... I will try the "*" as well. thanks +1

Comment: And what version of `recaptcha-bundle` installed with `"*"`?

Comment: Thank you so much victor, your answer helped :) I installed "v1.0.0" do you think it's better to use "*" ??

Comment: I think better will be `"~1.0.*"`, I would use so :) Maybe this core will be ever updated. But core `2.0` can be defferent from `1.0` and your code stop work after update

Comment: Okey, Thank you so much, I was struggling with this since yesterday :)

Answer (score 1):

Victor you are completely right. However some might still encounter issues with the versioning.
You will still have an issue unless you use the exact 1.0 version.

So after doing the require:

```
composer require "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle"
```

you will have do add the version 1.0 like:

```
Please provide a version constraint for the excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle requirement: 1.0.*
```